# Left Join table on condition which may be null and join null columns if condition is null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an `assignment` table which holds assignments created by a teacher in a particular class.

The `assignment` table has the following fields:

```
idAssignment (primary key), 
classId (foreign key), 
title, 
assignmentDesc, 
dateDue
```

I also have an `assignmentsubmissions` table where students in that class upload their submissions to the assignment.

The `assignmentsubmission` table has the following fields:

```
assignmentSubmissionId (primary key), 
assignmentId (foreign key), 
userId (foreign key), 
submission
```

Basically I want to join `assignmentsubmission` to `assignment` for a student in a particular class to see the assignments they have completed and not completed.

I have tried a number of different methods but this is my current SQL command:

```
SELECT * 
FROM assignment 
  LEFT JOIN assignmentsubmission 
    ON assignment.idAssignment = assignmentsubmission.assignmentId 
WHERE classId = 1234 
    AND ((userId = 1) OR (userId IS NULL))
```

The student mightn't have yet uploaded a submission to a particular assignment so in that case the `userId` will not exist for that `assignment` and I want to join `null` rows for `assignmentsubmission`. As it stands all that is happening is only the assignments which have been submitted are showing but I want all assignments, with a submission or null submission fields to be returned.

I'm really struggling with this problem so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: they have completed and not completed where is this information stored??

Comment: Drive from the `User` table. That would give you all of the assignments a student hasn't uploaded yet. If I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: @nikhilsugandh if a student uploads a submission it is strored in the assignmentsubmission table....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but the comparison to the student should be in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT a.*, (asu.userId IS NOT NULL) as completed_flag
FROM assignment a LEFT JOIN
     assignmentsubmission asu
     ON a.idAssignment = asu.assignmentId AND
        asu.userId = 1
WHERE a.classId = 1234 ;
```

This version introduces table aliases which make the query easier to write and to read.  Note that all column references are qualified -- meaning the table of origin is identified.

Comment: thanks a million for your answer. I had to add in at the end 

AND (asu.userId IS NULL OR asu.userId = 1) 

to account for both cases where either the student has a submission or doesn't. If you update the code above I will accept as the correct answer. Thank you again, only for you I would have been stuck on this problem a lot longer!

Comment: @RussellBrady . . . I think that information should go in a column in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Ahh ok I understand, I have that working now, thanks @GordonLinoff